# Generating Function for the adjusted Fibonacci numbers

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

The task is to find another relation for the adjusted Fibonacci numbers. I've found there genertaing function 
$$A(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x-x^{2}}$$

Furthermore I've created the generating function in a different way and now want to grab the correct coefficient.

Since $\hat{F}_{n}$ is the number of ways to add one and two to get $n$,

$$A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(x+x^{2})^{n}$$

Now I'm having trouble grabbing the $n^{th}$ coefficient.

It should be $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{n-k}$.

All I have so far is

$$A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}x^{2k}$$

Then I arrive at 
$$A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(1+x)x^{n}$$
Which does me no good. A hint would be very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We factor $1-x-x^2=(1-\phi x)(1-\psi x)$ for appropriate real numbers $\phi,\psi$.  Then solve the partial fractions problem $$\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{A}{1-\phi x} + \frac{B}{1-\psi x}$$

Then you have the sum of two geometric series.

Comment: Ok, doing that I got

$$\dfrac{2(1+\sqrt{5})}{\sqrt{5}} \left((-1)^{n}\left(\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n}+\left(\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n}\right)$$ But I need to show $\hat{F}_{n}=\sum_{k\geq 0}^{n}\binom{k}{n-k}$, and I have no idea where to proceed from there.

Comment: Your answer wasn't what I was looking for but your hint did lead me to an expression for $\hat{F}_{n}$. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.  This particular identity has a [combinatorial proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_with_combinatorial_proofs), but that's not what you want either.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't far off. I figured it out thanks for the help.